# The nature of changes in staged and unstaged files in git

Tags: git

After too many hours my concept of git is becoming confused. Can someone clarify me this situation.

I have a repository and I am in a particular commit, let's say a commit A

Some changes occur (due to me applying a patch but that can also be product of actual manual changes)

so I do `git status` and I have several "modified" staged files and some "new" unstaged files.

I add the files I want to keep. but what happens next?

I mean, if after adding the files I make a commit, I am in the state that I have one more commit , say commit B

BUT, the unstaged files do not "dissapear". They are still there.

Of course I can delete them manually (which makes them dissapear from the next `git status`) but what about the files that have been changed (and I **dont want them to change**)

Even if I do not commit them the changed files are there, so if I build the project they are going to interfere. I want them *just the way they were* before they were changed.

How can I do that?

Comment: your git folder is seperate from your active directory : stage or not staging will have no effect on the active directory

Comment: but, I *can see* that the unstaged new file is right there (with ls)

Comment: When you add a file to the index, you make a copy of the file and its contents into the index. When you then make a commit, the contents of the index becomes the contents of that commit. Your unstaged files are just left unstaged. You will have to either discard their changes, or add them to the index and make another commit.

Comment: If you have unstaged changes, in files that git is tracking, you can discard their changes using `git restore path/to/file(s)`

Comment: @KansaiRobot You might be helped to understand Git by this recent article of mine: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After too many hours my concept of git is becoming confused. Can someone clarify me this situation.

The path to clarity is this: *Changes* don't exist *in* Git.  You can get Git to *compute and then show* changes (between two snapshots), or to *read* changes (from a patch) and apply them (to a snapshot).  But everything *in* Git is a *snapshot*.

This includes Git's index / staging-area—it's a snapshot, like a commit, except that you can replace files in it—and to a lesser extent, your working tree.  Your working tree is not *in* Git, but Git will glance over at it; as long as it's not actively changing right now, Git will *see* a snapshot.

> I have a repository and I am in a particular commit, let's say a commit `A`.

This means that commit `A` is your *current commit*, usually because of some *current branch name* that (currently) selects commit `A`.  (Remember that the commit selected by some branch name can change.  Commit `A`, however, cannot change: all parts of any commit are frozen for all time.)

> Some changes occur (due to me applying a patch but that can also be product of actual manual changes),

Since the stuff *in* Git is snapshots, these changes must—necessarily—occur outside Git, e.g., in your working tree.  For instance, you might open some file in your editor and change it, and then write it back.  Or, you could use `git apply` (without `--index`) to make some changes in some working-tree file.

You can then—once the working tree file is updated—use `git add` to make Git replace the old index / staging-area snapshot copy with an updated snapshot copy.  This copy is ready to be committed: it is now in the special Git snapshot form, compressed and de-duplicated.  It's kind of half-in Git (though fully in if it's a duplicate, since it's then been de-duplicated against the already-fully-in copy).

> so I do `git status` and I have several "modified" staged files and some "new" unstaged files.

What `git status` does is run *two* `git diff`s, both with the `--name-status` settings internally (which speeds things up):

- First, it diffs the current commit, `A`, vs the index / staging-area.  Since Git stores files de-duplicated, this nearly-instantly tells Git which files exist as duplicates in both commit `A` and the staging area.  These files are uninteresting: Git says nothing at all about them.

  The remaining files either exist only in `A`, or only in the index / staging-area, or else exist in both but are different.  The `status` command will say that these files are *staged for commit*.  These are full copies!  They are compressed and de-duplicated, to be sure; but they are complete copies of the entire files.
- Now, having mentioned these `staged for commit` files, Git runs a diff between the files that are in its index / staging-area, and the (regular, ordinary) files in your working tree.  This diff has to work a bit harder since your working-tree files are actual ordinary files, not special Git-ized things with compression and de-duplication going on; but Git still has some cheat methods it can use.<sup>1</sup>

  Again, some files in Git's index will exactly match the working-tree copies.  For these files, Git will say nothing at all.  Only for files that differ in some way—existing only in the index, for instance, or having different contents—will Git name these as files *not staged for commit*.

Instead of showing files that only exist in your working tree as `A`dded, however, any file that's *in your working tree* but *not in Git's index* is—by definition!—an *untracked file*.  Git moves these file names to a separate section, and normally first filters this list against your `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` files.  If the untracked files are not *also* **ignored**, Git will tell you that they exist as untracked files.  If they *are* ignored, `git status` says nothing about them.  Note that this makes them indistinguishable from tracked but unmodified files.

> I add the files I want to keep. but what happens next?

Nothing special: `git add path` tells Git to copy the file from the given path in your working tree, into the snapshot in Git's index / staging-area.  Now a comparison between the staging copy—in the ready-to-commit, Git-ized, compressed, and de-duplicated form—and the working tree copy has them come out the same, so the *second* `git status` diff says nothing about the file.  Whether this changes the *first* `git status` diff, in regards to this particular file, depends on whether the updated de-duplicated index copy now matches the commit-`A` copy.

> Of course I can delete them manually (which makes them disappear from the next `git status`) but what about the files that have been changed (and I **don't want them to change**)?

You can tell Git to copy the commit-`A` copy of some file into its index.  Now the commit-`A` copy and the index copy match.  This assumes, of course, that the file exists *in* commit `A`; if it doesn't, you need to remove the index copy entirely, so that the lack-of-file in commit `A` matches the lack-of-file in Git's index.  (A minor drawback here is that the file becomes untracked.  Usually, that's fine anyway.)

To do this, use:

```
git reset HEAD -- path
```

(in any version of Git) or:

```
git restore --staged -- path
```

(in Git 2.23 or later).  These commands mean *copy from the current commit*—that's the default `--source` for this kind of `git restore`—into Git's index, without touching the working-tree copy.

To remove a file from Git's index without touching the working tree copy, you need:

```
git rm --cached -- path
```

As always, the `--` is optional unless the *`path`* argument resembles something else: a branch name, an option, etc.  It never hurts to use it, and sometimes it's not obvious that `foo` is both a branch name *and* a file name, in which case it helps Git out a lot to use it.

(Note that if you *do* want to touch the working tree copy, you'd use somewhat different commands, e.g., `git restore --staged --worktree`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>These cheats are the *cache* aspect of the index / staging-area / cache, and when they don't work, this part of `git status` can take a long time.  Git will notice if this goes slowly, and sometimes give you some hints about things you can do to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Answer : **Use Stash**

`git-stash` :  Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away

What is stash you may Ask  :

> Often, when you’ve been working on part of your project, things are in a messy state and you want to switch branches for a bit to work on something else. The problem is, you don’t want to do a commit of half-done work just so you can get back to this point later. The answer to this issue is the git stash command.
> Stashing takes the dirty state of your working directory — that is, your modified tracked files and staged changes — and saves it on a stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time (even on a different branch).

According to the [7.3 Git Tools - Stashing and Cleaning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) .

Personally I used **git stash** more than I thought I would use someday but using it as it mention above is a good way for switching between jobs when the current job is unfinished

You can see the full manual from [Git Stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)